# How can I get a picture file from an app I downloaded on my phone?

Tags: android, drawable, android-file

I downloaded an app onto my phone and the app features some nice images, which I would like to download for my own use (not breaking any copyright issues).

Is there any way to access the app's `drawable` folders and save the images?

Comment: If the app is FOSS, then you might already be able to access the images under a free license. If not you will have to contact the developer as @Laps has mentioned.

Comment: Designers spends their time to make images and designs. You shouldn't take someone's Time Consuming and hard work just like that.

Comment: @Jigar Thank you for the preaching, but I do not "take" anyone's hard work "just like that"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without decompiling the .apk file. I think your best bet would be to contact the developer and ask him for the images. If it isn't breaking copyright or anything (s)he might just send it to you.

Comment: "Not without decompiling the .apk file." - This is not true. It is possible to access other packages' Resources programmatically.